# Function between two metric spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I need to come up with:

- two metric spaces ( **X** , *d* ) and ( **Y** , *p* )
- A continuous function   f: **X** → **Y**
- A Cauchy sequence {x<sub>n</sub>} in **X** that isn't mapped to a Cauchy sequence in **Y**

My idea was to make the first metric space ℝ with the "usual" euclidean metric, and the second metric space would be ℝ with the discrete metric. Then the function would be anything continuous (like y=x or y=x^2). Since the second space has elements that are always a distance of 1 away from each other, you'd never map a Cauchy to a Cauchy...

But I'm awful at real analysis so I don't doubt there is an error here.

Comment: "(like y=x or y=x^2)".... Did you check if they are continuous?

Comment: @JohnMa

I believe so. y=x is uniformly continuous and y=x^2 is continuous but not uniformly so...I think

Comment: But you are using discrete metric. Your argument do not work here.

Comment: If $Y$ is discrete and $f:X\to Y$ is continuous , then for any $p\in X$ the set $\{f(p)\}$ is open and closed in $Y$ so $f^{-1}\{f(p)\}=\{q\in X :f(q)=f(p)\}$ is open and closed in $X.$ This may not be possible,depending on $X$ and $f$. For example if $X$ is connected and not empty, the image of $f$ will have to contain exactly one point.

Comment: @user254665    I see... If I understand correctly, because a continuous function between metric spaces maps closed subsets to closed subsets and open ones to other open ones, I have a problem because in a discrete metric space all subsets are open and closed so the preimages have to be open and closed but that's not possible with my choice of **X**..... So should I try something completely different and give up with the notion of discrete spaces?

Comment: No. The inverse image (preimage) of a closed set is closed and the inverse image of an open set is open,when the function is continuous. A function that maps every member of its domain to the same point  $q$ (a constant function) is continuous but the set $\{q\} $may fail to be open in the range.The continuous real function $f(x)=1/(1+x^2)$ maps $R$ onto $(0,1]$, and while $R$ is open and closed in $R$, its image $(0,1]$ is neither open nor closed in the reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $X$ be the reals in $(0,1)$ with the usual metric, and $Y$ the reals with the usual metric. Let $f(x)=\tan(\pi x/2)$.

Comment: I see. This function works out because you can make a convergent, and therefore cauchy, sequence that approaches 1 in the domain, but then the image of that sequence will diverge to infinity and therefore is not bounded, and not bounded implies not cauchy..... i think?

Comment: Thar's right. I left it to you to find an explicit sequence, I think you now know how to do that.